# How to combine mutiple column with comma separator?

Tags: ms-access

I have 11 columns as Note1,Note2,Note3,......Note11. I have write a query like this to combine

```
SELECT DormData.BuildingID, 
        DormData.DormRoomID, 
        DormData.Item, 
        DormData.Result, 
        DormData.InspectorID, 
        DormData.Date, 
        DormData.Qty, 
        DormData.Section, 
        (Note1 & " , " 
            & Note2 & ",  " 
            & Note3 & " , " 
            & Note4 & " , " 
            & Note5 & " ,  " 
            & Note6 & " , " 
            & Note7 & ", " 
            & Note8 & ", " 
            & Note9 & ", " 
            & Note10 & ", " 
            & Note11) AS Notes, 
        DormData.Comments, 
        DormData.Resident
FROM DormData;
```

It works and combine my records but problem is that it is not necessary that all the notes 
columns have values.suppose that if in a row there is values in only Note1 and Note5 then it gives output like not1,,,,note5. but I want it show "Note1,Note5"

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a presentation-layer issue, not a SQL issue. There is no logical reason why you should want to do this in the SQL statement.

Comment: It also smells like a flawed database design.  If you've got 11 notes fields and you're expecting many of them to be Null then it's time to start thinking about a separate Notes table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is [IIF() aka immediate if](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209192).

For example, on the orders table in the [Northwind sample database](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=c6661372-8dbe-422b-8676-c632d66c529c):
    IIF(orders.ShipRegion IS NOT NULL, orders.ShipRegion & ',', ''

Or a more complete query:

```
SELECT 
    orders.OrderID, orders.CustomerID, orders.EmployeeID, 

    orders.ShipVia, orders.Freight, 
    (orders.ShipName & ',' & orders.ShipCity & ',' & IIF(orders.ShipRegion IS NOT NULL, orders.ShipRegion & ',', '') & orders.ShipPostalCode & ',' & orders.ShipCountry) AS Expr1
FROM orders
WHERE orders.[OrderID]=10282;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an Iif statement in each 'Note1 * ","' section to check for null values.

```
Iif(IsNull(Note1), Note1, Note1 & ",")
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Small quibble:  `Note1 Is Null` will be more performant than `IsNull(Note1)`.  The former is functionality built-in to the Jet/ACE engine; the latter is a VBA function that requires processing external to Jet/ACE.

Comment: Actually, I think IsNull() is a Jet/ACE SQL function as well, but your observation is correct as a recommendation since Is Null can use indexes, while IsNull() cannot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the vba function route, the following function will do the job:

```
Function JoinStrings(Delimiter As String, _
                     ParamArray StringsToJoin() As Variant) As String
Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In StringsToJoin
        If Not IsNull(v) Then
            If Len(JoinStrings) = 0 Then
                JoinStrings = v
            Else
                JoinStrings = JoinStrings & Delimiter & v
            End If
        End If
    Next v
End Function
```

You would call it like this:

```
JoinStrings(", ", Note1, Note2, Note3, Note4, Note5, Note6, Note7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a trick with how Null expressions and concatenation works in Access:

```
Note1 & (", " + Note2) & (", " + Note3)...
```

When concatenating text, Access treats Null as it were an empty string. But if you're "adding", the Null would cause the expression inside the parentheses to result in Null. As long as your notes aren't numeric, this will work.

Comment: That does not seem to work from inside the query designer of Access 2007. SELECT 
    orders.OrderID, orders.CustomerID, orders.EmployeeID, 

    orders.ShipVia, orders.Freight, 
    (orders.ShipName & ',' & orders.ShipCity & ',' & (orders.ShipRegion  & ',') & orders.ShipPostalCode & ',' & orders.ShipCountry) AS Expr1
FROM orders
WHERE orders.[OrderID]=10282;

Comment: @Justin: You missed the trick.  It has nothing to do with parentheses...it's the difference between how the concatenation operator `&` and the addition operator `+` works.

Comment: That's a handy trick, but the way you've written it it will fail if Note1 is Null (ie, you will end up with a leading comma).

Comment: @mwolfe02 True. You'll run into a similar problem with a final trailing comma with IIf. Either approach works best if it can be assumed that the first note is never null. If you have to deal with Nulls at any point, a VB function may be best.

Answer (score 0):

A modification to TheOtherTimDuncan' solution, which will work well to concatenate two (or may be three) Notes. Use IIF() to have delimiter or blank based on whether Note1 is Null. It could be like:
Note1 & (IIF(Note1 Is Null, "",", ") + Note2) & (IIF((Note1 & Note2) Is Null, "",", ") + Note3)...